# Javascript - Empty nodes issue

Tags: javascript, html

I'am learning about using nodes and I have a little issue, then I don't konw why it doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lrzy0263/

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" id="couleur"> 
 <button id="ajouter">Ajouter</button>
 <ul id="liste"></ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("ajouter").addEventListener('click',
    function (){
        var couleur = document.getElementById("couleur").value;
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var texte =       document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("couleur").value);
        li.appendChild(texte);
        document.getElementById("liste").appendChild(li);
        document.getElementById("couleur").value = "";
        document.getElementById("couleur").focus();
        if(couleur.length == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
)
document.getElementById("liste").addEventListener('click',
    function(e){
          document.getElementById("liste").removeChild(e.target);
    }
)
```

The problem is when the input is empty and when I click to add an "li", it continues to add empty "li" O_o

How can I stop the event ? I already have the condition when the length = 0 but it doesn't work if I only return false.

If you have some ideas, I am open with it =)

Have a nice day

Comment: So why are you returning false after you add the empty element? Why are you not checking before you add the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement that checks if the length is zero is at the end of your function. Returning `false` doesn't cancel code that has already run; you have to return *before* the LI gets added. Move that if statement to the top of the function, like so:

```
document.getElementById("ajouter").addEventListener('click',
    function (){
        var couleur = document.getElementById("couleur").value;
        if(couleur.length == 0){
            return false;
        }
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var texte =       document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("couleur").value);
        li.appendChild(texte);
        document.getElementById("liste").appendChild(li);
        document.getElementById("couleur").value = "";
        document.getElementById("couleur").focus();
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you !!, But How did you know that ? My question is very "stupid" if I can use the term, I don't know how you thought that the solution was only to set my if statement before my "real" code O_O

Comment: The code directly in the order it's written, from one line to the next. In your code, you were first creating an `li` element, and then doing the `if(couleur.length == 0)` check. Because the check happened after, it was too late to stop the `li` from being created. But when you have the check before you create the `li`, the check will cause the function to return before the `li` is created. Using a `return` statement tells the computer "ok, we're done with this function, don't run the rest of it".

Comment: I understand !! Thank you for your help, I will be more careful about that.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes. You main issues was that you needed to put your append code inside of the if block. Then you check to see if the value from the input is not blank. If so the code appends the elements.

I also created variables for the DOM elements so you don't have to keep doing the "document" traversing.

```
document.getElementById("ajouter").addEventListener('click',
        function (){
           var couleur = document.getElementById("couleur"),
               couleurVal = couleur.value,
               ul = document.getElementById("liste"),
               li = document.createElement("li"),
               texte = document.createTextNode(couleurVal);

          if(couleurVal !== ''){
            li.appendChild(texte);
            ul.appendChild(li);
            couleur.value = '';
           }
        }
    );

    document.getElementById("liste").addEventListener('click',
        function(e){
              document.getElementById("liste").removeChild(e.target);
        }
    );
```